# Pandas: Collapsing a multi-index dataframe into a single row and column separated by a comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, multi-index

I have a df that looks like this:

`df.set_index(['pid','vid]).sort_values(by = 'time')`

Before:

```
                          pid    time 

    id           vid      
    
    id1         vis_id1    pid1    t_0      
                vis_id1    pid2    t_1
                vis_id1    pid1    t_2
                vis_id1    pid2    t_3
                vis_id1    pid1    t_4       
    
    id2         vis_id2    pid1    t_3      
                vis_id2    pid2    t_4      
                vis_id2    pid2    t_5      
                vis_id2    pid2    t_6
                vis_id2    pid2    t_7
```

I want to collapse all of the `pid` such that for every `id` we have the following df

```
                                  pid       
id           vid      

id1         vis_id1    pid1, pid2, pid1, pid2, pid1               

id2         vis_id2    pid1, pid2, pid2, pid2, pid2
```

I have tried transposing the data first and then applying `[steps].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)` but if I can avoid the transposition all together that would save me a lot of computing power

Comment: Hi ! Thanks, got put on another project i willreturn to this very soon. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with aggregation with `', '.join`, as follows:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'vid'])[['pid']].agg(', '.join)
```

Note the double square bracket `[[...]]` used around `pid` in `[['pid']]`

**Result:**

```
                                      pid
id  vid                                  
id1 vis_id1  pid1, pid2, pid1, pid2, pid1
id2 vis_id2  pid1, pid2, pid2, pid2, pid2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'vid'], values='pid', aggfunc=', '.join)
print(out)

# Output:
                                      pid
id  vid                                  
id1 vis_id1  pid1, pid2, pid1, pid2, pid1
id2 vis_id2  pid1, pid2, pid2, pid2, pid2
```